# Missing Required Modules in Swift framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, module-map

I built a swift framework with two Objective-C classes. After I released a framework, it works on my environment. But I imported this to another environment, but it didn't work. "Missing Require Modules..."
Here is my module.

```
module RSAUtil [system] {
    header "RSAUtil.h"
    export *
}

module NetworkTool [system] {
    header "NetworkTool.h"
    export *
}

module openssl [system] {

    header "OpenSSL_Lib/include-ios/openssl/bio.h"
    header "OpenSSL_Lib/include-ios/openssl/opensslv.h"
    header "OpenSSL_Lib/include-ios/openssl/rsa.h"
    header "OpenSSL_Lib/include-ios/openssl/ssl.h"
    header "OpenSSL_Lib/include-ios/openssl/err.h"
    header "OpenSSL_Lib/include-ios/openssl/pem.h"

    export *
}
```

I tried many solutions but failed. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: I am getting same issue. @Ivan, you solved this issue ?

Comment: same issue here. @gstream79, did you find any solution?